# Determine plugin name from within plugin_action_links filter

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, filters, hooks

Is there any way to determine what plugin the [plugin_action_links](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/plugin_action_links_%28plugin_file_name%29) filter is addressing when it processes the filter?

I'm trying to add some actions for each plugin on the `/wp-admin/plugins.php` page. Code looks as so:

```
public function _add_plugin_links(){
    $plugins = get_plugins();
    foreach($plugins as $k=>$plugin){
        add_filter( 'plugin_action_links_' . $k, array(&$this, '_plugin_action_links') );
    } // foreach $plugins
}

public function _plugin_action_links( $links ) {
   $plugin = 'test'; // Somehow get plugin name here?
   $links[] = 'Plugin name is: '.$plugin;
   return $links;
}
```

I am able to append this text to the end of each plugin link list, but cannot determine exactly which plugin I am adding the text to. Adding a global variable from within `_add_plugin_links()` simply returns the very last plugin that is parsed from the plugins list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are currently [four filters](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-plugins-list-table.php#L365) and they carry lots of information:

```
$prefix = $screen->in_admin( 'network' ) ? 'network_admin_' : '';
$actions = apply_filters( $prefix . 'plugin_action_links', array_filter( $actions ), $plugin_file, $plugin_data, $context );
$actions = apply_filters( $prefix . "plugin_action_links_$plugin_file", $actions, $plugin_file, $plugin_data, $context );
```

This is a var dump of the parameters for Advanced Custom Fields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [activate] => <a href="plugins.php?action=activate&amp;plugin=advanced-custom-fields%2Facf.php&amp;plugin_status=all&amp;paged=1&amp;s&amp;_wpnonce=62d37299ca" title="Activate this plugin for all sites in this network" class="edit">Network Activate</a>
            [edit] => <a href="plugin-editor.php?file=advanced-custom-fields/acf.php" title="Open this file in the Plugin Editor" class="edit">Edit</a>
            [delete] => <a href="plugins.php?action=delete-selected&amp;checked%5B0%5D=advanced-custom-fields%2Facf.php&amp;plugin_status=all&amp;paged=1&amp;s&amp;_wpnonce=b7f1cf2b36" title="Delete this plugin" class="delete">Delete</a>
        )
    [1] => advanced-custom-fields/acf.php
    [2] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Advanced Custom Fields
            [PluginURI] => http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/
            [Version] => 4.2.2
            [Description] => Fully customise WordPress edit screens with powerful fields. Boasting a professional interface and a powerfull API, it’s a must have for any web developer working with WordPress. Field types include: Wysiwyg, text, textarea, image, file, select, checkbox, page link, post object, date picker, color picker, repeater, flexible content, gallery and more!
            [Author] => Elliot Condon
            [AuthorURI] => http://www.elliotcondon.com/
            [TextDomain] => 
            [DomainPath] => 
            [Network] => 
            [Title] => Advanced Custom Fields
            [AuthorName] => Elliot Condon
        )
    [3] => all
)
```

You could use the bare `plugin_actions_link` and detect the plugin file, but it's easier with the second. Example adding an Action Link to ACF in `wp-admin/network/plugins.php`:

```
add_filter( 'network_admin_plugin_action_links_advanced-custom-fields/acf.php', function( $actions, $plugin_file, $plugin_data, $context )
{
    $actions['hello'] = 'Hello worlds!';
    return $actions;
}, 10, 4 );
```

<sub>*Another filter of interest: [**`plugin_row_meta`**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-plugins-list-table.php#L420).*</sub>

Comment: Great info! I glazed over this part of `class-wp-plugins-list-table.php` earlier today, thanks :)